# MySQL query optimization and performance

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, inner-join, query-performance

I have the following table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
`id_product` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_product`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products_vars` (
`id_product` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`id_product_var` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`price` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,
`discount` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`stock` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`coming_soon` enum('y','n') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'n',
`date_add` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`date_update` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`active` enum('y','n') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'n',
PRIMARY KEY (`id_product_var`),
KEY `id_product` (`id_product`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

ALTER TABLE `products_vars`
ADD CONSTRAINT `products_vars_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_product`) REFERENCES `products` (`id_product`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

I need to get the cheapest product with its correct ID, the below query works well but I think it's a little slow, so I was wondering if there is another way to do so.

```
SELECT p.id_product, pv.coming_soon, pv.date_add, pv.price * (1 - (pv.discount / 100)) AS price, MAX(pv.stock) AS stock, MAX(pv.date_add) AS date_add
FROM products AS p
INNER JOIN products_vars AS pv USING(id_product)
INNER JOIN (SELECT pv.id_product, MIN(pv.price * (1 - (pv.discount / 100))) AS min_price
    FROM products_vars AS pv
    WHERE pv.active = 'y'
    GROUP BY pv.id_product) AS pv2
    ON pv2.id_product = pv.id_product
        AND min_price = pv.price * (1 - (pv.discount / 100))
WHERE pv.active = 'y'
GROUP BY pv.id_product
```

And one last thing please: the table "products_vars" can contain several variation of the product (colors or sizes), what's the best way to tell if AT LEAST one of them has `"coming_soon" = "n"`?

Comment: This question has been asked(badly) lots of times here on SO. It's not a duplicate as the answer is often different. But if you go read some of the previous questions AND THE COMMENTS you'll see this question cannot be answered without at least providing the EXPLAIN plan and table structures.

Comment: Thanks symcbean for your reply. Believe, i checked several threads, but didn't find an answer to my questions! maybe you con point me to some of them!! <br>
the table structure is exactly the one i gave but a little simplified without all the columns...

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.

Comment: Hi Rick, I have updated my initial messge.
Thanks

Comment: @Websphere Please provide your actual query, instead of `...` and `WHERE CONDITION`. These details are extremely important for performance related questions. Each column you select or filter by can have an impact on performance. Also, please fix the table definition to actually show the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE product_vars`. The PRIMARY KEY column in that statement doesn't even exist in your table.

Comment: Sorry again, didn't put the whole query just to prevent you from too much reading... I have once again updated the initial message with full and tested sql code. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is the query that works for me for the moment:

```
SELECT 
    p.id_product,
    pv.coming_soon,
    pv.date_add,
    pv.price * (1 - (pv.discount / 100)) AS price,
    MAX(pv.stock) AS stock,
    MAX(pv.date_add) AS date_add,
    (SELECT pv2.coming_soon FROM products_vars AS pv2 WHERE pv2.id_product = p.id_product AND pv2.coming_soon = 'n' LIMIT 1) AS coming_soon
FROM products AS p
INNER JOIN products_vars AS pv USING(id_product)
INNER JOIN (SELECT pv.id_product, MIN(pv.price * (1 - (pv.discount / 100))) AS min_price
    FROM products_vars AS pv
    WHERE pv.active = 'y'
    GROUP BY pv.id_product) AS pv2
    ON pv2.id_product = pv.id_product
        AND min_price = pv.price * (1 - (pv.discount / 100))
WHERE pv.active = 'y'
GROUP BY pv.id_product
ORDER BY stock DESC
```

It working great but I'm wondering if: 
1- it's optimized
2- how to sort products by name but only for available ones (stock > 0), then the unavailable products come at last?

Thanks